# UITableview images from Sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I want to display images in a tableView from SQLite. Here is my retrieve image code from SQLite code. How do I load the images in the tableview?

```
-(void) retrieveData{
sqlite3 * database;
NSMutableArray *prodnamemutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *prodpricemutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *prodimagemutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *databasename=@"contacts.sqlite";  // Your database Name.

NSArray * documentpath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES);

NSString * DocDir=[documentpath objectAtIndex:0];

NSString * databasepath=[DocDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databasename];

if(sqlite3_open([databasepath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM contacts";  // Your Tablename

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        [prodnamemutable removeAllObjects];

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            [prodnamemutable addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]];
            [prodpricemutable addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)]];

            int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 0);
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 0) length:length];
            [prodimagemutable addObject:imageData];
            NSLog(@"Length from db : %lu", (unsigned long)[imageData length]);
            imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:prodimagemutable];
            NSLog(@"image found.%@",imageArray);
        }
    }
    nameArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:prodnamemutable];
    priceArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:prodpricemutable];
    NSLog(@"nameArray:%@",nameArray);
    [[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[nameArray count]];
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

This will convert your image `NSData` to `UIImage` now this image can be shown on any `UIImageView`.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [prodimagemutable count];    //count number of row from image array.
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
             cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                           reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        }
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[prodimagemutable objectAtIndex: indexpath.row]] ;
        return cell;
    }
//Below use for set height of cell

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        return 80;// or the height you want.

}
```

Comment: Confirm UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate in your VC.

Comment: but the first image repeat the second row and the second row image is displayed in third row, how to fix.

Comment: If I add new item on table its shown the first row of image. give some suggestions please.

Comment: Repeat of image may be the result of your prodimage array, did you checked it for distinct images.

Comment: and for the second question can you please elaborate what is actually happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92003/discussion-between-karunpant75-and-jkannan).

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you separated the code into multiple classes like the following

**1. DBManager**

```
@interface DBManager : NSObject
- (NSArray *)getImages;
@end

@implementation DBManager
- (NSArray *)getImages {
    // put your code to retrieve the images from the database
    // use the following to convert from NSData to UIImage
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
@end
```

**2. ImagesTableViewController**

```
@interface ImagesTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray* images;
@end


@implementation ImagesTableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.images = [dbManager getImages];
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.images.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    }
    cell.imageView.image = self.images[indexpath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```